# Vim want to write on a block

Tags: vim

I have this file

```
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:       
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
~                                                                                                                                     
~
```

I want to enter a description(copy and paste)
in a block after dvb-apps: 
so result like this

```
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:       
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps: Bla bla,description bla bla bla
dvb-apps: Bla bla,description bla bla bla
dvb-apps: Bla bla,description bla bla bla
dvb-apps: Bla bla,description bla bla bla
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
```

If i use the standard paste from console i obtain

```
dvb-apps: Bla bla,description bla bla bla
Bla bla,description bla bla bla
Bla bla,description bla bla bla
Bla bla,description bla bla bla
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
```

How to paste into a block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy the content to your document in vim as you do, presumably with the middle mouse button in X, using insert mode, but on separate lines.

Then go to the first column of the first of the newly inserted lines and go into visual block mode `CTRL+v` where you can select the content. The only issue here could be different line lengths that sometimes make it hard to select the whole content in visual block. You might have to add some whitespace to the last line first in order to be able to select all columns of all lines.

After having done so, press `d` for delete, navigate to the correct column of the first target line and paste with `p`.

Alternatively, doing the task but not an actual solution to your question, asking to do it in vim, would be to create two separate files:

```
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:       
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
dvb-apps:
~
```

and

```
Bla bla,description bla bla bla
Bla bla,description bla bla bla
Bla bla,description bla bla bla
Bla bla,description bla bla bla


~
```

and then use

```
paste <FILE1> <FILE2> > <OUTPUTFILE>
```

to put both files together.

Comment: Sorry it ,doesn't work

Comment: What's the problem? I just tried, works fine for me.

Comment: Yes works fine,i have bad read first

Answer (score 3):

With my [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355), you can force the paste to be *blockwise*, which is what you want here. So instead of entering insert mode and pasting with the middle-mouse button (which I suppose you've done), use the `"*` register together with the plugin's `gbp` mapping.

Comment: The plugin is Impressive! +1

Answer (score 2):

If you have `xclip` (`sudo apt-get install xclip` or similar) you can access the system (i.e. Xorg) clipboard from the command line, using `xclip -o`.
This way, you can `!paste - <(xclip -o)` or define a key mapping (for instance `<LEADER>p`)
as:

```
:map <LEADER>p .,$!paste - <(xclip -o)<NL>
```

and use `<LEADER>p` to paste the current X clipboad contents.

`<LEADER>` defaults to `\` (so in the above example `\p` will perform the paste command) but can be changed to anything, `-` for instance, by `:let mapleader="-"`.